# Há alguma maneira de se passar o valor de uma $_SESSION para um link?

Tags: php, session

Há um sistema de login com  email e senha,porém,como já utilizei $_SESSION para capturar o id da sessão e o nome do usuario que está logado,não seria problema guardar email e senha também,sendo assim,gostaria de fazer com que esse processo de login fosse automatizado,clicando apenas em qualquer link que desse acesso pro interior do site.
O problema é:Como passar os valores dessas sessões para uma variável?

Estou usando esse redirecionamento para fazer a proteção das páginas:

```
    if(empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="login.php"; 
    </script>
    <?php
    exit;
    }
```

Portanto,uma vez que ele é a única coisa que preciso para que o acesso ao sistema seja garantido,há alguma maneira de colocar pelo menos o ID embutido no link que será posteriormente gerado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode imprimir sua session e concatenar da forma que achar melhor.

ex print:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>
```

ex concatenar:

```
www.site.com/id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>
```

ou

```
<?php echo "www.site.com/id=" . $_SESSION['id']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o header(), ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
header("Location: url_de_redirecionamento?id=$_SESSION['id']")
```